# iframes - overflow: hidden doesn't work on Chrome & HTML5

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I try to display Amazon reviews in an iframe. This worked fine for me until a few weeks when the page wasn't displayed in the right way on chrome anymore.

As you can see in the picture, some of the other elements on the page get overlapped by the content from the iframe that should be hidden. I can hover over elements and they flicker. Sometimes the price and button are display and sometimes they are not. I am very sure the `overflow:hidden` is just not working right!

I work with a div around the iframe.

```
.outerdiv
{
    width:250px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.inneriframe
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left: -10px;
    width:1280px;
    height:1200px;
}
```

My iframe has the `scrolling="no"` attribute.

[overflow problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks7XD.png)